# Handler as a method parameter

Tags: java, android, android-handler, accessibility

Why some api have handler as a method parameter? What are the possible use cases? Specifically I need someone to explain why we need a handler in the 
dispatchgesture method. I am trying to perform drag operation on behalf of user using this dispatchgesture method.

```
boolean dispatchGesture (GestureDescription gesture, 
                AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback callback, 
                Handler handler)
```

Comment: this is useful if you want to run your `callback` in non UI thread

Comment: is it possible to perform drag using this method on user behalf ... @pskink

Comment: never tried it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `dispatchGesture` [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)),

> **callback**  *AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback:* The object to
> call back when the status of the gesture is known. If null, no status
> is reported.
>
> **handler**   *Handler*: The handler on which to call back the
> callback object. If null, the object is called back on the service's
> main thread.

That basically means, if you don't provide a Handler then the given callback will run on main thread.

Running expensive UI updater task in main thread in general is always discouraged. So, when you're passing a handler as method param, most of the time it is there to lighten the UI thread up by taking off some of the heavy duty tasks, process it in another thread(handler, in this case) and post the result when its done.

Comment: this answers my question about handlers ... but what about the drag functionality that  I want to implement . Is it possible ? @fluffyBatman

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that.